# Write $f'(x)$ for the usual derivative of $f(x)$ from calculus. Show that the remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by $(x−a)^2$ is $f'(a)(x−a) + f(a)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I do have a pretty big hint. By the division algorithm in R[x], there exist polynomials $q(x),r(x)\in\Bbb{R}[x]$ such that $f(x)=q(x)(x-a)^2+r(x)$ and either $r(x)=0$ or $deg(r(x))<deg(x-a)^2)=2$. Therefore, $r(x)=rx+s$ for some $r,s\in\Bbb{R}$. Your goal is to show that $r=f'(a)$ and $s=f(a)-a*f'(a)$. I'm really unsure about where to continue with it from the hint.

Comment: Hint: $\;f'(x)=q'(x)(x-a)^2+2q(x)(x-a)+r'(x)\,$.

Comment: Another hint: What happens if you plug in $x=a$ in the equation?  Then what happens if you plug in $x=a$ into dxiv's equation?  Also, I would avoid reusing $r$ as a coefficient of $r(x)$ - could easily cause unnecessary confusion.

Comment: Move $a$ to the origin, do the division and then move the result back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what we do is, that from the division algorithm we get that $$f(x) = q(x)(x-a)^2 + cx+d$$
since you have shown that the remainder can have at most degree $1$. Put $x=a$ here to get that $f(a) = ca + d$.

From here, The first thing you should do is differentiate:
$$
f'(x) = q'(x)(x-a)^2 + 2q(x)(x-a) + c
$$

Now, suppose we put $x=a$, this gives $f'(a) = c$, since the other two cancel out.

From the above equation:
$$
f(a) = af'(a) + d \implies d = f(a) - af'(a)
$$

Now, we can combine the expressions:
$$
f(x) = q(x)(x-a)^2 + cx + d = q(x)(x-a)^2 + x(f'(a)) + (f(a) - af'(a)) \\ =
q(x)(x-a)^2 + f'(a)(x-a) + f(a)
$$

This shows that the remainder obtained is as desired. You should also see what happens when you divide by $(x-a)^3$ and so on : then you can actually have a formula for the remainder.

Comment: Yeah that all makes perfect sense. Thanks so much.